# Typing for a general promise library

Tags: typescript, promise

I have a function that takes a promise library.

```
function takeLib(promiseLibrary) {

}
```

I'd like to type it so it has to be a class with `.then` and `.catch` methods.

I created an abstract class like this:

```
export abstract class PromiseLibraryAbstract {
  abstract then(...args: any[]): any
  abstract catch(...args: any[]): any
}
```

However I get typing issues when I try and use it:

```
export type PromiseLibrary = typeof PromiseLibraryAbstract

const x: PromiseLibrary = Promise

function takeLib(promiseLibrary: PromiseLibrary) {

}

takeLib(Promise)
```

How can I type a general class shape?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=17&pln=6&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOABSggFsBLFYAGUqQygE8BBVdLeAbwCg5EHDNjgwAFsAB2ACgB08hFADmKAFyJJzANoBdAJTqEm-oLTCcCGJjFyFytRu37DxgL69eoSLFHMwwEjIqGnpGRWY4AF5ffwgAM0CKajoGJjYhLg9MCEk0OBB1UiSQ1PCoxODgDziAV0lsShzRBABrFKRpMCDk0LTC7pKwlj04Pl53XhhW9ukiyr0gA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing constructor definition, that's why types are not compatible. You can use something similar to original `Promise` constructor definition:

```
export abstract class PromiseLibraryAbstract {
  constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: any) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {

  }
  // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOABSggFsBLFYAGUqQygE8BBVdLeAbwCg44mCADs0UAK7ZoAClDBM4mNABccaVGAoIuAG7BV0nQlzjgAflUJhzAJRwAvAD44OiJQAmAGjgaAVvJgDDQIRC0RrOycXN3dI51cPOz5+OABfFOQxLjgYAAtgYWkAOhKEKABzFEtrAG0AXRtq5gyODGxBBBhMXOLSiqrw5nrGwd503lBIWBzmMGASMioaekYy5gcZuYgAMwWKajoGJjZWrl5eIVF4EFVSfeWjtY27peBz7fFhbEoRHIQAa0OSGkYEWBxWx1uYIeqxYSXO4xgAKB0heBxsQA)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have an issue with calling `takeLib` - you need to pass `x` instead of `Promise`..
Plus, `x` is of type `PromiseLibraryAbstract`

```
export abstract class PromiseLibraryAbstract {
  abstract then(...args: any[]): any
  abstract catch(...args: any[]): any
}

export type PromiseLibrary = typeof PromiseLibraryAbstract

const x: PromiseLibrary = PromiseLibraryAbstract

function takeLib(promiseLibrary: PromiseLibrary) {

}

takeLib(x)
```